# Place ggplot in a specific coordinate of a background image by using ggdraw and draw_plot (cowplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I have this ggplot figure by using the well-known database `mtcars`.

```
ggmtcars <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point(size=2, shape=23) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0), color = "red", lty = 2) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0), color = "red", lty = 2) +
  theme_void()
```

I want to introduce a background image by using `draw_image()` from the **cowplot** package. The image is a open-source image from the Wikimedia Commons repository (copy all the link and paste in the bar).

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:2018_Honda_Jazz_(GK5_MY18)_VTi-S_hatchback_(2018-08-06)_01.jpg

I saved the picture with the name `coche.jpg`. The dimension of this image is **4281 x 2329 pixels** (width x height).

Now I select that image as the background of the scatterplot, which include the entire image in the plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(magick)

ggdraw() +
  draw_image("images/coche.jpg") +
  draw_plot(ggmtcars)
```

Now, the point is that I would like to place the ggplot figure (`ggmtcars`) in a specific point of the background image. This needs to fulfill two important points:

1. The bottom left corner of `ggmtcars` needs to coincide with
2. A specific coordinate (x,y in pixels, exactly 768 x 1668 px) of the background image.

I employed and scaled accordingly the ggplot in the background image:

```
ggdraw() +
  draw_image("coche.jpg") +
  draw_plot(ggmtcars,
            scale = 0.1007119,
            hjust = 0,
            vjust = 0)
```

[image]

Now I would like to place the bottom left corner of the ggplot in this coordinate of the background image (768 x 1668 pixels).

Is there an easy way to move the plot to this part?

[image]